# When is $n^n + 1$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I came across this problem in a book, though the 'solution' was short and hard to comprehend.

I know that $n^n$ has to be even, so n is even. I wrote it like $2x^{2x}$. However, the book claimed that because n is even, n can be written as $2^{2^{t(2k+1)}}$ and odd divisors like $2k+1$ isn't possible so $n = 2^{2^t}$ and the final answer is $${\left( 2^{2^t} \right)}^{2^{2^t}}$$
I understand that Fermat's Little Theorem may be of use here, but not why the t is there in $t(2k + 1)$ or why it has to be a $2^{2^n}$ structure. $2^n$ sure because $2$ is the smallest even and $2^n$ is helpful for simplifying with Fermat's Little Theorem, and $(2k+1)$ to compliment that with odds, since $2k$ is even and thus the mod would be $1$ (mod even), but not the $2^{2^n}$ or $t$ term.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's $(2x)^{2x}$, not $2x^{2x}$.

Comment: This was already asked. The next possible such prime after $257$ is $F_{70}$ , the $70$ th Fermat number. It is so huge that there is no hope to detect it as a prime, should this be the case. We can safely assume that beyond $257$ there is no such prime.

Comment: To see that such a prime must be a fermat prime, first consider that $n$ has to be a power of $2$. This gives $n^n+1=(2^k)^{(2^k)}+1=2^{k\cdot 2^k}+1$. But $k$ must be some power of $2$ as well, say $k=2^m$. This gives the $m+2^m$-th Fermat-number.

Comment: By the way, $F_{70}$ has $$355\ 393\ 490\ 465\ 494\ 856\ 466$$ digits

Comment: Minor quibble: $1^1+1$ is prime even though $n=1$ is not even....

Comment: @BarryCipra In fact this is not even a fermat-number, correctly pointed out. But for $n>1$ the below answer applies.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiNumberoftheFirstKind.html is worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy to prove fact that $x^k+1$ has a factor $x+1$ if k is odd. The $k=1$ case is trivial, so let's only consider odd $k>1$.

Substituting $x=y^m$ you get that $y^{km}+1$ has a factor $y^m+1$ if k is odd.

Applying this to your problem you find that in order for $n^n+1$ to be prime, the exponent $n$ cannot have a non-trivial odd factor, and must therefore be a power of $2$.

So $n=2^k$ for some $k$. We now have $n^n +1 = (2^k)^{2^k} +1 = 2^{k2^k}+1$, and once again we find that for this to be prime the exponent cannot have a non-trivial odd factor, so $k$ is also a power of $2$, and the result follows.